# VB 6: The project not be built because it references a project which does not have a binary compatibility file set

Tags: vb6

I haven't done VB 6 development for nearly a decade. Any advice on how to deal with this error?

```
The project 'ProjectB' can not be built because it 
references project 'C:\VSS\Foo\ProjectA\ProjectA.vbp'
which does not have a binary compatibility file set.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161137

If you can open project A, you want to change the Component tab of the Project Properties dialog box to Binary Compatible and then recompile.

Then in project B, reestablish the reference to the dll/ocx file produced in the compiling of project A.

At least that is what I remember from 10 years ago and a quick google search.

Comment: Your first step was enough, I didn't have to touch project B at all. Still, I'm rather confused as to why it needs binary compatibility turned on in the first place. Oh well, it isn't like that is a bad thing.

Comment: it is a matter of keeping the interface guids the same when the projects are registered in the system registry.